# Concat inside rails query conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails.
I would like to write this SQL query in the rails way :

```
select * from USER where ((name+' '+firstname) like %search%) or ((firstname+' '+name) like %search%) or (name like %search%)  or (firstname like %search%)
```

How can i do this?

Comment: What's going to be in search? kinsonTo and nyHop seem sort of unlikely

Comment: does not look like a query that would scale at all

Comment: search is just a random string

Answer (score 1):

You can write this sql query in the rails way: 
In the User_controller:

```
User.where("name = ? AND LOWER(firstname) LIKE LOWER(?)", "%#{ params[:name]}%", "%#{ params[:key]}%").
```

Comment: and if i want to write inside the model ? how can i do this using  "find(:all, :conditions => " ?

Answer (score 0):

User.find (:name=>"here you can enter the name of your user")

here you can send the parameter in method 
def capitalize_name(name)
 name.downcase
end

then you can use like 
User.find (:name=>"#{capitalize_name(name)}")

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but posting this answer because it might save someone's time. In `postgres` when you want to concat two columns, use `||`:

```
User.where("(name || ' ' || firstname) LIKE ?", "#{search_term}")
```

**Note:** wrap your query string in double quotes since the empty string being concatenated (|| **' '** ||) needs to be in a single quotes.